# How to design multinational database tables with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC with Entity Framework Core code-first (for a SQL Server database) to develop an application as a learning exercise. From the offset I want the database & application design to be capable of handling multinational scenarios.

To keep this simple, let's assume I have an `Employee` table & an `EmployeeDetails` table. How would you go about designing the database so that the `EmployeeDetails` are different depending on the country?

For example, in the UK we have a National Insurance number, where as this data column wouldn't apply to an employee in a different country.

1. Would you have 1 table with all possible data columns, but disable them in the UI where appropriate? This however would prevent you from marking columns as being required (not nullable).
2. Would you have multiple `EmployeeDetails` tables, one for each country? This would mean the data retrieval code would have to branch. Furthermore, you would have multiple tables to maintain and probably incur column replication.
3. Would you have a common `EmployeeDetails` table and have related tables branching off of it containing data fields specific to a country? i.e. (`EmployeeDetails > ED_UK`) & (`EmployeeDetails > ED_France`) & (`EmployeeDetails > ED_US`)

Having dynamic data columns will also mean having to build a dynamic HTML UI capable of rendering only the applicable columns. I can't imagine one would want to build multiple UI's, one for each country, to essentially achieve the same task.

I very much welcome all feedback and advice.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty *broad* question as I don't believe there is a definitive answer.  However when you describe something like in this way..

> To keep this simple, let's assume I have an Employee table & an EmployeeDetails table. How would you go about designing the database so that the EmployeeDetails are different depending on the Country?

This sounds like inheritance might be helpful solving the problem.  So ignoring the data storage for a minute, you could have domain entities that look like:

```
// abstract maybe...
public class EmployeeBase
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  // etc...
}

// UKEmployee or EmployeeUK whatever..
public class UKEmployee : EmployeeBase
{
  // Uk Specific Properties
}
```

I always like to see if the presentation level has any issues with an architecture before looking at SQL.  Since you mentioned MVC (I'd use automapper to map to view models) for now I'd just map them to similar models...

```
public class EmployeeBaseVM { ... }      
public class UKEmployeeVM : EmployeeBaseVM { ... }
```

And I would imagine the easy way would be something like..

```
// Encapsulating class for and index method on a controller
public class IndexVM
{
  public UKEmployeeVM { get; set; }
}
```

I would make two display templates (so far):

UKEmployeeVM.cshtml

```
@model UKEmployeeVM

@* display shared properties *@
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m, "EmployeeBaseVM")

@* display specific properties *@
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
```

EmployeeBaseVM.cshtml

```
@model EmployeeBaseVM

@* I hope you get where this is going *@
```

So the presentation level seems fairly easy, so lets work on the data storage.  Since you're using EF, I'd suggest using [Table per Type Inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt).  No need to go into the details, that page does a good job of explaining it.

However, it doesn't go into detail about SQL structure.  It appears you have pseudo-unlimited countries so instead of..

```
[dbo].[EmployeeBase]
[dbo].[UKEmployee]
```

which seems like it might get unwieldy, I'd suggest switching to Schemas for your segmentations.

```
[base].[Employee]
[UK].[Employee]
```

The disadvantage to this is that any new countries or functionality require new schemas, EF, Domain, Viewmodels. I believe it's easier to write code that knows exactly the model then to try an write some dynamic code that is trying to do a catch-all for *the future*.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

In this specific example, most countries have some sort of identifier number that is used to identify the employee to the tax collector.  The UK may call it the National Insurance number, the US may call it the Social Security Number, other countries will have other names for it, but it is conceptually the same thing across countries.  In that case, I would have a single column to store the tax identification number but localize the label in the UI so that the American version says "Social Security Number", the UK version says "National Insurance number", etc.

If you were setting up a full-blown payroll system that would need to have a bunch of country-specific tax and witholding attributes, then you're probably looking at separate tables.  Each country is going to have a reasonably unique setup with very specific laws and regulations that need to be coded for so it would make sense to have a set of tables for the information that the IRS needs in the US, a separate set of tables for the information that the HMRC needs in the UK, etc.  Individual employees would be set up in one or more tax regimes (presumably most would be in only one) and the code that interacts with those tables would likely be very specialized.  You'd probably be writing the module for a particular country's taxing authority from scratch and using some sort of plug-in framework to the main application rather than trying to write a generic UI that would dynamically know how to reconfigure itself to ask for the information the IRS wants vs. the information the HMRC wants as well as to implement the rules specific to those taxing authorities.